# Gerar APK - erro

Tags: android, apk

Olá, estou tentando gerar APK assinado e está dando erro:

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Eu acho que meu app não tem mais que 64 K.

Meu Gradle está assim:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.schwaner.teste"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
```

}

Detalhe não estou usando nenhum serviço do Google, é normal aparecer duas dependencias do Google?

No meu Android Manifest também está duas chaves do Google.

O que eu preciso fazer para conseguir gerar o APK assinado?
Obrigada.

Comment: Consegue dar um double check se não está utilizando nenhum serviço do Google? Se puder dar uma busca por GoogleApiClient no seu código. Porque a dependência do `play-services:9.8.0` adiciona todos os módulos de serviços do Google Play Services. Caso esteja utilizando, você teria que  remover o `play-services:9.8.0` e adicionar os módulos mais específicos.

Comment: Oi. Não estou utilizando, eu até tentei colocar um mapa e uma geocoder. Mas daí, decidi fazer uma Intent para consultar o Googlemaps no celular do usuário caso ele tenha instalado.

Comment: Posso apagar esta linha então?

Comment: Sim, deve apagar sim, ela gera senão dezenas ou centenas de milhares dex count ao seu app. Se for o caso deve apagar o `play-services-appindexing:9.8.0` também.

Comment: Agora apareceu isto:

Comment: To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

:app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:validateSigningRelease
:app:packageRelease
:app:assembleReleas

Comment: Não é erro não, acredito que o build esteja sendo completado não? Isso é só um aviso de que o build vai ser mais rápido se adicionar mais memória para o gradle. Mas isso precisa de uma outra configuração e foge ao escopo da pergunta.